# Python Синтаксис Задача

Tags: python, синтаксис

Дано Дана последовательность целых чисел. Первое число в последовательности нечетное. Найти сумму всех идущих подряд в начале последовательности нечетных чисел. Инструкцию `if` не использовать.

```
a=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
i=0
k=0
while a[i]%2!=0:
    k+=a[i]
    i+=1
print(k)
```

Выдает ошибку

> ```
>  File "121.py", line 4
>     while a[i]%2!=0:
>                   ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

***Repl Closed***
Как правильно оформить `while a[i]%2!=0` ?????
Или например как сравнить `a[i]` c `a[i+1]`(эта уже другая задача, просто подскажите как обращаться к элементу массива)?
(использую python 3)

Comment: у вас последовательность (массив) строк, а в условии последовательность целых чисел. Попробуйте так: `a = [1,5,3,7,2,1,4]`

Comment: Код из вопроса такой ошибки не выдает. Проверьте, что в коде, который вы запускаете, действительно стоит двоеточие.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["1","3","5","7","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
i = 0
k = 0

while int(a[i])%2:
    k += int(a[i])
    i += 1

print(k)
16
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, какой IDE ты пользуешься, но VS Code выдаёт ошибку такую:

```
    while a[i]%2!=0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Сразу становится понятно, что нужно преобразовать тип элементов массива (списка).
Сделать это можно двумя способами:

1. в исходном массиве задать числа, а не строки

   ```
   i = 0
   k = 0
   while a[i] % 2 != 0:
       k += a[i]
       i += 1
   print(k)
   ```
2. в цикле сделать преобразование строки в число с использованием `int(a[i])` (в этом случае стоит не забыть ещё раз сделать преобразование при сложении `k += int(a[i])`

   ```
   i = 0
   k = 0
   while int(a[i]) % 2 != 0:
       k += int(a[i])
       i += 1
   print(k)
   ```

И ещё один совет - не пренебрегай пробелами при написании кода. Читабельность вырастет в разы (см. PEP-8 - [на сайте python.org](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), [на сайте pythonworld.ru](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html))